# Filesystem permissions making a cURL-based caching script break

Tags: php, permissions, fwrite

I'm writing this cURL script in PHP. It's purpose is to take a product or category code given to it (which type of code it is is ambiguous at that point, sure, it's possible for a category and a product to have the same code, but that's what business rules are for and what this question is NOT about), and then attempt to load either a product or category page on our shopping cart with it. Whichever page returns a 200 response then gets its output cached into an html file in the DocumentRoot.

Problem is, the DocumentRoot isn't owned by apache and I don't feel comfortable giving global write permissions to the DocumentRoot, so while the script works for the most part, the page doesn't get cached.

I do not have root or su access to the server and cannot get either. I tried writing the file to the /tmp/ directory and then moving it, but the permissions won't let me. Is there a way around this without opening up a security hole? If not, would this be possible with a Perl CGI script or would I face the same problem?

Comment: why not to keep it in the /tmp/?

Comment: Because this works in tandem with some Apache URL rewriting. If the requested file doesn't exist, it generates it from the shopping cart plaftorm and then caches it as the expected file.

Comment: so what? what's wrong if cached file stays in tmp?

Comment: I was aiming to keep the rewrite rules simple (ha!). Right now it's basically

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+).html$ /scripts/cache.php?code=$1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If apache doesn't have the rights do something, then there's nothing you can do to bypass it short of putting in an suid program to force a permissions set, use suphp to do the same, or just grant the required permissions.

Another option is to grant Apache write permissions in a SUBdirectory off the documentroot, and then use some mod_rewrite magic to make requests for those cached files get transparently rewritten to use the subdir instead. that way you've got a writeable directory, but don't have the issues of making the parent document root writeable.